# removing zeros from a part of a ggpaired plot using ggplot_build

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to remove zeros from **only** the violin part of this graph

I tried using the ggplot_build function but I don't get the desired outcome and somehow it removes the statistical test.

Am I doing something wrong?
I attach code and picture of the problem

[image]

```
library(introdataviz)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)

#set seed
set.seed(42)

#build dunny data
first <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,15,2)))
second <- sample(c(rep(0,100), rnorm(50,10,1)))
df <- data.frame(first, second)


# build plot
p1 <- ggpaired(df,cond1 = "first", cond2 = "second",line.color = "gray")+
   stat_compare_means(paired = TRUE)+
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin( trim = TRUE,alpha = .4) + ylim(0,22)
#create ggplot_build object
p1_build <- ggplot_build(p1)

#remove zeros from violin plot part
p1_build$data[[4]] <- subset(p1_build$data[[4]], first != 0 & second != 0)
p1_build$data[[5]] <- subset(p1_build$data[[5]], first != 0 & second != 0)

#produce new graph
p2 <- ggplot_gtable(p1_build)
grid.draw(p2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the zeros from the violin plot it's probably easier to use a filtered dataset for `geom_split_violin`:

```
library(introdataviz)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)

ggpaired(df, cond1 = "first", cond2 = "second", line.color = "gray") +
  stat_compare_means(paired = TRUE) +
  introdataviz::geom_split_violin(
    data = ~ subset(.x, first != 0 & second != 0), 
    trim = TRUE, alpha = .4
  ) +
  ylim(0, 22)
```

[image]